# Regex php preg_match multiple occurrences in string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have the following string:

> findByHouseByStreetByPlain

How can I match to values after each "By". I have managed to find the first "By" value, but I can't  get it going that it gives me all the matches for the value after "By".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thsi regex should work for you:

```
<?php 
$ptn = "#(?:By([A-Za-z]+?))(?=By|$)#";
$str = "findByByteByHouseNumber";
preg_match_all($ptn, $str, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

this will be the output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => ByByte
            [1] => ByHouseNumber
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Byte
            [1] => HouseNumber
        )

)
```

Comment: Can work but remember that this regex only matches if the string starts with a capital and is followed by small caps. For example, findByHouSeByStreet will not match

Comment: Well that's how it is supposed to be written in camel-case.. for more complex examples..

Comment: I interpreted that the seperator is "By"

Answer (score 1):

Some use of lookahead will do it

```
By(.*?)(?=By|$)
```

In php this become

```
preg_match_all('/By(.*?)(?=By|$)/', $subject, $result, PREG_SET_ORDER);
for ($matchi = 0; $matchi < count($result); $matchi++) {
    for ($backrefi = 0; $backrefi < count($result[$matchi]); $backrefi++) {
        # Matched text = $result[$matchi][$backrefi];
    } 
}
```

Comment: Just add some grouping if you want to extract submatches

Answer (score 0):

Try this code below:

```
$pattern = "/[^By]+/";
$string = "findByHouseByStreetByPlain";
preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: It also match with the "find".

Comment: And will also fail with `findByByte` (for example)

Answer (score 0):

my string is different:

> HouseByStreetByPlain

then i use the following regex:

```
<?php 
$ptn = "/(?<=By|^)(?:.+?)(?=(By|$))/i";
$str = "HouseByStreetByPlain";
preg_match_all($ptn, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => House
            [1] => Street
            [2] => Plain
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => By
            [1] => By
            [2] => 
        )

)
```